# If the Hero is Ego-driven, but what is the Self/Soul?

Tags: archetypes

According to psychologist Carl Jung, there are divisions into one's mind. The "Self" (often described as "Higher-Self" or "Soul") is what hold all of those divisions together (or try to). It is what gives balance and stability of who you *truly* are or can be.

[image: 1]

**The hero archetype is the personification of the ego** (I won't explain it here, it would be a huge explanation.). In Campbell's and Vogler's writings, there are mentions about the "Shadow" as well. It is portrayed as an antagonist to the hero, but not necessarily the villain.

[image]

This "ego-driven" journey is about proving something to the world. The Hero has something that is not well acepted in his society and he has to left in order to mature himself for then he can return renewed and stronger. They often want save the world aganist what he (or his society) considered to be evil, but there are other people on the other side that have their own heroes. So we got ourselves a bunch of blue and red heroes fighting aganist each other.

**There isn't, a specific journey for the Self,** which is the central part of the human's psyche. We tend to forget it in our polarized society as we need it more than ever.

### **What journeys and/or archetypes can be told as a journey/archetype for the "Self?"**

I'm not talking about the "I'am" the "me" but the psycholical concept of the Self. If You are not familiar with it, here are some brief explanations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want more information, the key-words are: Self, Soul (in psychology), Ego, Carl Jung

Comment: If you guys can help, there is an open question about "Psyche's Journey" which is portraid as the "Journey of the soul." https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/what-is-the-symbolism-behind-psyches-tasks

Answer (score 2):

The Self is the sum-total of various psychological components, housed in a physical body. And as a person is more than just a body, the Self is more than a house -- it is a Home.

That said, the Self is usually represented symbolically by some residential structure. Thus the psychological significance of repetitive dreams featuring houses. They represent the psyche seeking to identify with its true Self.

Therefore in dreams or stories, abodes are always very significant, and examples might be:

Castle
Cottage
Hut
Middle-class abode
Haunted Mansion
Manor House
Farmhouse
Tent
Mountain
Wood
River
Homelessness

But iconic forms of houses represent more than just structures (physical bodies), whether grand or humble. Facade alone is in the realm of persona, which is just one component of the Self. And many houses are not homes. Yet the Home / Self (or lack thereof) is what is really being represented by the various types of abodes in mythology.

Thus there is the tacit understanding in tales such as the story of Cinderella, that the transformation from subjugation (immaturity) to freedom and happiness (maturity and fulfillment) is strongly associated with a move to a better home (i.e. in Cinderella's case, the castle). Of course, in order to make that transition, Cinderella and the Prince (anima + animus or passive + active components of the psyche) have to find and fall in love with one another.

Of course, very materialistically minded people don't fully understand the psychological significance of such myths, placing all the importance on being glamorous, marrying up, and taking out mortgages. In other words, their focus is on the facade, and they have a very difficult time making any house (no matter how grand or humble) -- a Home.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that the **"Heroine's Journey"** from fairy tales and Disney movies **can be considered as the "Soul's Journey"** because the heroine often needs to receive help from other people in order to reach her goal. Different from the masculine hero, it is common that he passes the dangers all by himself. But **the female hero needs connection and relationship.**

Examples:

- Redhood was helped by the Huntsman to kill the wolf.
- Cinderella only outbraves the stepmother after she met the prince with the help of the fairy godmother.
- What about the seven dwarves that follow Snow White?
- Other examples can be found throughout other tales.

The soul can only live with a relationship. There is no such thing as an individual soul. What can be called as "individual" is the ego, and the ego is egoist by definition. The soul, on the other hand, embraces the totality of the subject and even embraces the shadow, often told as a friend.

I think that one may also say that a "Mentor's" journey or archetype can be said as a journey/archetype for the Self, as psychology say that its function is to give more consciousness, perception and comprehension of life. But in this case, in order for you to "conduct" and teach like a mentor, you must first be conducted and be taught as a student.

Like you are doing now.

The hero's journey is the most common structure in Hollywood movies and stories, but we are not heroes all of the time. Nowadays we live polarized by opinions and politic views because everyone wants to be a hero, but a hero defends what one believes. It is too easy to be King when there is no one left to pawn.

So, are you going to be a hero, or you will be your *self?*

Comment: I'm not sure the male journey is entirely without assistance assistance.  Gilgamesh needed Enkidu.  Odysseus would never have survived without the patronage of Athena, or even without assistance from mortal women such as [Nausicaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausicaa).  I'd also caution against the idea that the soul requires an other--it's simply one paradigm.  The Buddhist saint may renounce the world in attaining enlightenment, a solitary pursuit (although it is, again, worth mentioning that Milarepa only attained this after his sister brought him some food and drink.)

Comment: But the process of enlightnment is more about connecting not only to another being, but "all" beings. It is some kind of advanced compassion and connection twoards all that exists. And true, the male journey can be entirely without assistance as well, I was just considering Hero's Journey by Campbell in which one of the steps is "Tests, enemies and allies" who may help him reach the Elixir. But yes, he can.